# Preventing SQL Injection in Rails while using Javascript Query Builder

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, query-builder

I would like to use jQuery query builder as a tool in a multi-user app: http://mistic100.github.io/jQuery-QueryBuilder/

I understand using such an tool could potentially carry great risks for SQL injection if not setup properly.

I am aware of the traditional methods of preventing against SQL injection (i.e. hardcoding the WHERE statement rather than inserting user-inputed strings directly in), but in this case that would prove to be a bit more difficult given how dynamic and flexible we are trying to keep things.

I am wondering if there are any easy ways to setup a secure process while using something like this query builder. The main concern is one user being able to access and/or modify another user's records (I am not as concerned about them messing with their own records, but they're all in the same database).

One idea I had is doing a find and replace for any problematic words (i.e. DROP, etc), but I understand this would place limitations on user-input (i.e. if they wanted to search records that matched "He dropped the ball")...and also is perhaps not foolproof.

Are there any other methods that might work, short of having to code in some complicated algorithm to generate SQL code server side?

Answer (score 1):

In general you should only accept really "filter" params on GET requests for an index. Even then you don't want to take all params willy-nilly and shove them into a WHERE clause.

If you want to let the user create complex conditions you would create a simple parser which takes user input and builds SQL statements via Arel.

Or you might want to use an existing engine for full text search such as Lucene.